# Allow IIS7.5 to serve up a file larger then 2 GB

Tags: iis

I have a website running on IIS7.5 on a Windows 2008 R2 server. I'm attempting to download a file from the site that is 3GB. But the download just stops at 2GB. No error in the log.

What I have done:

```
Set maxRequestEntityAllowed to 10000000 for the site.
Set maxRequestEntityAllowed to 10000000 for IIS.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you using IE 7 at the time of this question?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298618

Comment: @Ek0nomik -- HAHAHAHA. Nope.

Comment: You never accepted an answer or answered your own question.  Did you end up resolving the issue?  If so, you should add answer.  The current answer seems irrelevant as that's for *request* filtering.

Comment: @Ek0nomik -- It's still an issue. Thus the lack of a accepted answer or an answer provided by me.

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure what `maxRequestEntityAllowed` does, but, I know `maxAllowedContentLength` should work, just make sure you add it to the correct place inside your `web.config` file.

As you said you do not have an existing `web.config` file create one with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength=”9999999999″ />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There isn't a config for this site... so I'll give it a go with a blank config and see what happens.

Comment: @NitroxDM How did you do the setting in the site like you said in your question? :/

Comment: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/asp/limits -- I'm guessing that is just for caching... but it's the closest thing I have found so far.

Comment: Doesn't seam to matter where I put it I get an error "the configuration section 'Security' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration."

Comment: @NitroDM, ... Ok, I have updated the question, copy and paste exactly in to a new web.config file, and put it in the same folder as the file.

Comment: Your sample config is more or less the same as mine. ;) It still gives the same error on line 4.

Comment: @NitroxDM What does it report the error as?

Comment: "the configuration section 'Security' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration."

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these things plus the asp limits thing - you have to have the following in a web.config file in the root of the website:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
       <staticContent>
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".ad3" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".torrent" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
       </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
```

That's a day and night fix for me...